# How does exact function w.r.t standard deviation while configuring splunk alert work?

Tags: splunk, stdev

I have been trying to set up an alert to see the spike in traffic in terms of standard deviation. 
I am setting the upper bound as below:

```
upperBound=(avg+stdev*exact(4)).
```

However, I am not able to understand what does avg+stdev*exact(4) mean in terms of spike and deviation. What will be spike the in traffic be if I write as (avg+stdev*exact(4))?

Hence, how are these below different? and what should I choose?

```
avg+stdev*exact(5))

avg+stdev*exact(4))

avg+stdev*exact(3))

avg+stdev*exact(2))
```

Comment: You are defining the upper bound (or threshold) of the spike as 4 times the standard deviation compared to what I assume is the current rolling average. What you set the multiplier for the standard deviation to be just depends on your use case, I don't think anyone here can reliably answer that

Comment: That being said, Splunk has built in anomaly detection searches you may want to use instead of hardcoded multipliers

Comment: The `exact` function uses greater precision when doing calculations.  It adds no value to whole numbers.  `avg + stdev*exact(4)` is the same as `avg + stdev*4`.